# Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm)

Tags: javascript, node.js, maven, npm

I've got this little problem with maven -

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) on project xxx-frontend: Could not download Node.js: Could not download https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.11.2/node-v8.11.2-linux-x64.tar.gz: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty -> [Help 1]`

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, on windows it works fine. What can I possibly do with this? Link to nodejs is fine.

I've tried:
 - removing ~/m2/repository/com/github/eirslett, but it didn't help,
 - using global and intellij maven, 3.5.2 and 3.3.9 respectively, 
 - multiple mvn clean install

Could it be a problem with firewall? If yes, then why and how to fix it?
Or at least if somebody could give a clue as to what's going on with this crap :/

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>xxx-frontend</artifactId>
<version>0.0.4</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>xxx::Frontend</name>
<description>frontend</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>xx.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <relativePath>..</relativePath>
</parent>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>build-with-front</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v8.11.2</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>6.1.0</npmVersion>
                        <installDirectory>node</installDirectory>
                    </configuration>

                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>install node and npm</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        </execution>

                        <execution>
                            <id>npm install</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>install</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>

                        <execution>
                            <id>npm build</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>run maven:build</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <filesets>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>dist</directory>
                            </fileset>
                        </filesets>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a top answer when googling this error, if you're facing this issue and on a Mac with the new M1 chip you need to upgrade to at least version `1.11.0` for this plugin to work.